# PDF manipulation with placeholders

Tags: java, pdf, itext, wildcard, pdfbox

I am looking for a Java tool that can manipulate an existing PDF containing placeholders like `${foo}`. I want to generate mail merge documents from that.

I found a lot of solutions with forms but this seems not suitable for me. Currently I generate the PDF with iText but this is a really annoying task to convert existing Word files or similar. I didn't find another solution with iText so far.

I also used JODReports in conjunction with JODConverter but it is necessary to run OpenOffice as a service and the performance is bad.

Comment: Replacing PDF content is fickle thing at best. Problems may arise due to different reasons: a) If replacement is longer than the placeholder, reflowing the paragraph in question and maybe more may become necessary. Reflowing PDF in general is a really difficult task. b) If embedded fonts are used, the glyphs for the characters in the replacement may not have been embedded. Thus, those glyphs cannot be shown unless the font in question is present locally, much time is invested in extension of embedded fonts, and then you still need some luck. c) Sometimes text recognition is impossible.

Comment: `PDF` isn't text.  Don't attempt find/replace.

Comment: Since you generate your templates with iText, why don't you go one step further and generate the final document from scratch with iText too?

Comment: there is another tool called JasperReports that allows for intricate PDF generation and I've experienced good performance with it

Comment: See my answer on this (duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447316/replace-data-in-a-pdf-file-using-java

Comment: I really understand your points. And it became clear that it is not as easy as I thought. Meanwhile I tried http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ReplaceString.html and mentioned problems occurred, reflowing the paragraph etc. But one thing: PDF has to be not necessarily the source because my customers sent Word files. But it takes at least one day to convert a Word file into iText code.

Comment: If C#/vba is an option, it'll be fairly easy to manipulate the original Word file then. If you have to stick to Java, have a look at Apache POI. You'll just have to run a straight DOC->PDF converter then.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll give Apache POI a try. Also I found XDocReport which might be an option.